# CodeIgniter adding static pages

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    public function view($page='home')
    {
        if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            echo "Sorry, file does not exist";
        }
        else
        {
            $data['title']=ucfirst($page);
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('pages/'.$page,$data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hello I am using the above code as my controller file and the home page works fine, however after adding another page and using the link on the home page I get a 404 error, this leads me to think I need something adding to the above coding, but I don't know what or how as I have just started using CodeIgniter.

I would also like to know either how to load another header page with any other pages so that the menu item for the new page is active, or to just use one header page and menu and make any new pages set the menu item as active.

Any help would be welcome thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I strongly recommended you to take look at [Tutorial Codeigniter](http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/)

Comment: I have been looking around for an answer to this but had not found one that is why I posted here, however I will take a look at your link thanks.

I also would not call it off topic.

Comment: Rohil_PHPBeginner, Your edit is how my code is, must have been a pasting error here.

Comment: `if(!file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))` to `if(!file_exists(APPPATH . 'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))`